# Delete query is working but data is not deleted?

Tags: php, database, row-removal

Why is my delete query not deleting data from database?

This is the code:

```
<?php
include ("includes/database.php");
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['username']){

    header('location:index.php?error=You are not an administrator');
}else{
    $delete_id=$_GET['id'];
    $user=$_SESSION['username'];
    $delete='delete from `wall` where `ID`="'.$delete_id.'" AND `User_id`="'.$user.'" ';
    $Query=mysql_query($delete) or die (mysql_error()); 
    if ($Query){
        header('location:User_page.php');
    }
}
?>
```

The query is working because I do a redirect to `User_page.php`, but the data from database is not deleted.

Comment: You're comparing `User_id` with username in `$user`?

Comment: What happens if you `echo $delete;` and leave out the redirect? That's Debugging 101 in situations like this: Make sure the query is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: If the query is valid, it won't return false, even if it doesn't "do" anything.  1) Change "delete from" to "select * from" and check if it finds anything.  (It won't since it didn't delete) 2) Check mysql_affected_rows() > 0 to see if anything changed.

Comment: Very constructive comment Marc. Bravo with your "help"

Comment: Write after `$delete=...`, `echo $delete; die();`, and check is that query correct.

Comment: echoing $delete just show me the query i've given :(

Comment: query is as it should be. the db connection is ok! 
i don't know why it can't delete the row from database :/

Answer (score 0):

The redirect works if the query doesn't have an error, it doesn't mean the query changed anything. Try: [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Also are you supposed to be using the `$delete_id` variable?

Comment: yes because $delete id is getting what id number on the database should be deleted.

Comment: the mysql_affected_rows()
showed me that there wasnt any record deleted. :/

Comment: i know its not .. i just want to know why it can't delete the row from the table when the query is right? :( plz help.